# Creating Special SEO Route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following entities:

> Companies -> Blog -> Articles -> Comments

Each company has a blog (or blogs), which have articles and comments.

The URLs are created like this:

> {controller}/{Action}/{id}
>
> Blog/Edit/1

I want to put the company before it, for SEO purposes and it's more logical:

> SampleCo/Blog/Edit

SampleCo may also have a website with pages like:

> SampleCo/myPage.vbhtml

What's the best way to go about this?  Thank you for your help.

Note:  I have seen the links on multi-tenancy but I don't that that will be needed.  I don't need separate instances as everything is foreign-keyed (companies to blogs, blogs to articles, articles to comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe me you dont want to mess with the default route it will give you a headache, you can leave the default as it is, and create a secondary Route like :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

    routes.MapRoute(
                "SEORoute1", // Route name
                "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And when you need to use the route just use this helper:

```
@Html.RouteLink("LinkText","SEORoute1",new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", company = item.Name, id = item.Code })
```

Answer (score 2):

In global.asax.cs you should be able to replace the default route with this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The only problem is that this goes for all request, so if you use/need the default route for other parts of the site, you'll have to find another solution.

In your controllers you would have:

```
public class BlogController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Edit(String company, int id) {
    }
}
```

Comment: By using route constraints to ensure that {company} is a valid company (either text or id) and that {controller} is a valid controller and {action} is a valid action on that controller you can easily make the route only apply to certain requests.